# When running unit tests in ReSharper, how can I see the overall execution time?

Tags: resharper

I'd like to know how long all my tests took to run? Is that possible?

Comment: There is a button "Show Time" in toolbar of Usint Test Session window. But unfortunatly the root node just shows the time duration of last test, not time duration of all tests (at least in ReSharper 5.1.3). :-(

Comment: I saw that and thought "so it must record overall time somewhere"

Comment: In I realise this is old, but in the current version I can see the consolidated test times.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're probably looking to profile your unit tests, and since you're running them with ReSharper, the natural choice would be to install [dotTrace Performance](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/) and [profile unit tests](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/webhelp/Profiling_Guidelines__Profiling_Unit_Tests.html) using this combination.

Comment: I'll check it out, I dont think I have the license for that product thoough

Answer (score 60):

Yes. Select *Options(is in the Unit Test Sessions pane)->Show Time* and then select *Options->Group by Project Structure* in unit test window.

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer because your solution only requires Reshaper and no other JetBrains products although @gorohoroh's solution will yield far more detailed information if you have dotTrace.

Comment: unfortunately there seems to be a maximum test name length, which if any test is expanded and shown whose name exceeds that then no times are shown

Comment: So much easier than mucking with dotTrace

Comment: This does not work, when the test projects are in two different folders below the solution folder. It will then only show the time aggregated by folder without an overall time.

Answer (score 1):

For people looking for the **wall clock time** of how much time a test execution took (it may be different to the time shown on the root node in the unit test session), here is how you can see it:

1. Open the unit test **session window**
2. Click the **gear** (**⚙**) icon on the top icon bar
3. Select **Diagnostics → Show Last Launch Log**
4. There you can **see from the logs**: search the `RunTestsStage` string for start and finish entries.

In my case, the test session window showed 1 min 34 sec, but in reality they only took around 23 seconds (because of running tests in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

If all your tests in your test session are in one assembly and if you use MSTest framework you could use methods marked with **`[AssemblyInitialize()]`** and **`[AssemblyCleanup()]`** for measuring time duration.

See example in [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for using these attributes.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good solution given the question is asking about Resharper and @dmitryZyr offers a Resharper specific solution.